# docker bridging localhost port

Tags: node.js, docker, networking, botframework

There is a chatbot-service running on my local machine at Port `50160`. This port is for receiving messages from my nodejs-service in the docker container. To send messages to the chat-service the docker-container has port `8080`open. This works fine.

I start it using `docker run -p 8080:8080  registry.gitlab.com/abc/def/adapter-xyz`.

But sending a response from the docker-container to the chatbot returns the following error in the docker container:

```
ChatConnector: message received.
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:50160
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
```

It seems that it cannot send back a response to chatbot (running on my machine). Any idea?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `0.0.0.0:50160`?

Comment: I can't change this IP-Address, because sadly its set from a dependency. Running the service outside from docker works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the IP address of the host instead of 127.0.0.1. The address can be easily extracted by executing:

```
docker network inspect -f '{{ range .IPAM.Config }}{{.Gateway}}{{end}}' bridge
```

I read in the comments that you can't change that address (btw, hardcoding is never a good idea). Another solution would be to add a iptables rule in the container itself to redirect the inbound traffic to port 50160 to the host machine. I'm not very fond of this idea since it's pretty hacky but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run --network=host
```

can set the network of the container as host, so you can access.127.0.0.1 from the container. 
but this doesn't work on osx